# Simple program adding "D" to output

Tags: c, printf

I have a very simple program that just prints the number of newlines as an integer and I get a "D" after every number.

Sample input:
d [enter]
e  [enter]
f  [enter]
Ctrl-D [enter]

Sample output:
3D

What am I doing wrong?

This is verbatim from The C Programming Language 2nd edition, pg. 19:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()  
{  
    int c, nl;  
    nl = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)  
        if (c == '\n')  
            ++nl;  
    printf("%d\n", nl);  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the D isn't just coming from the Ctrl+D?

Comment: What platform are you running on?  MacOS X by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for answering, everybody.  I'm running OpenBSD 4.5.

Comment: See also: [C program prints 0D instead of 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306225/c-program-prints-0d-instead-of-0).

Answer (score 4):

I think the D comes from the Ctrl D.  The console outputs ^D as its standard echo logic, prior to passing the corresponding char (or rather here lack of char, i.e. EOF status) to getchar(), however, and rightfully, not sending a cr/lf.  The C program then sends its 3,  et voila...

Try the program by typing more than 9 CR before exiting and the problem should "go away", i.e. not show.

Comment: I am not really sure never seen such stuff

Comment: You appear to be correct.  You can confirm this explanation by adding a couple of extra newlines to the beginning of the printf string like this: printf("\n\n%d\n", nl);

The shell prints the ^D, and the printf overwrites the caret with its output.

Comment: @RageZ: neither had I before now, but testing on MacOS X (10.5.8) shows exactly that behaviour - much to my surprise.

Answer (score 2):

Change the print line to this:

printf("\n%d\n", nl);

Then you'll see that when you hit ctrl-d, you get "^D" on the line.  Only since you didn't press ctrl-D followed by Enter, then it's not on a newline in your original program.  Not all systems will echo ctrl-d back to you, but it does on OS-X for example.  So it ends up messing up the output if you print a one-digit number.  You'll have to work around it.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's an `stty` setting that controls this?

Comment: Answering my own comment/question: `stty echoctl` enables it and `stty -echoctl` disables it (the echoing of control characters such as `^D`, that is).

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me with GCC, whether I pipe in input or manually type it in and finish with ^D.

```
$ ./a.out
1
2
3
3
$ echo -ne "1\n2\n3\n" | ./a.out
3
```

It's probably like @mjv said, and the console is echoing the D back to you  <s>-- you're on Windows, right?  I think that's normal for the Windows console</s>.

Comment: Mark, on Windows it's the ctrl+z that sends EOF.