# Why does C program print 0D instead of 0? (When EOF sent as Ctrl+D)

Tags: c, macos

OSX 10.6.8, GCC 4.2 86_64

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count lines in input */
main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

Run

```
./a.out
```

press `ctrl+d` to send EOF

```
0D
```

It should be just 0. Why does it append D? What does it mean?

Comment: If you are pressing ctrl+D, then it sounds like the D comes from the terminal ... e.g. it doesn't relate to the printf (or the code at all?). What happens if you try it with say, `more` or `less`? What about if you pipe the input in to the program?

Comment: Does that happen every time you send EOF with <kbd>CTR</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>, to any program, or just to this test? I think that the `D` besides the `0` comes just from the key combination above.

Comment: i got 0 when i run on my linux machine

Comment: @pst no, D doesn't come from that — ctrl+D is a shortcut to send EOF

Comment: @Nicolás no, only with this example.

Comment: @Mr.32 well, it may be related to only OSX/BSD

Comment: See also: [Simple program adding D to output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450324/simple-program-adding-d-to-output).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've seen this one - it confused me, too.

The terminal is echoing `^D` and then the `0` is output from the program, overwriting the caret.

You can demonstrate this by changing the print format in your program to `"\n%d\n"`.

---

When asked 'Why?', I went exploring.  The answer is in the tty settings.  For my terminal, the output from `stty -a` is:

```
speed 9600 baud; 65 rows; 120 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^X; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Notice the `echoctl` at the end of the second line - it is for 'echo control characters'.

```
$ stty -echoctl
$ cat > /dev/null
asdsadasd
$ stty echoctl
$ cat > /dev/null
asasada^D
$
```

You can't see it, but for each `cat` command, I typed a <kbd>Control-D</kbd> at the end of the line of `asd` characters, and a second one after hitting return.  The prompt erased the second echoed `^D` in the second example.

So, if you don't like the control characters being echoed, turn the echoing off:

```
stty -echoctl
```

The shell can also get in the way; I experimented with <kbd>Control-R</kbd> and my shell (`bash`) decided to go into

```
(reverse-i-search)`': aasadasdadadasdadadadadadsad
```

I'd typed the unoriginal sequence of 'asd' characters and then typed <kbd>Control-R</kbd>, and this is where I ended up in the shell.  I interrupted; I'm not sure what a reverse-i-search is, but I suspect it is Emacs-ish; it was not what I expected.

Comment: Wow, that was spot on! But why does it happen only in this particular case? Or does it happen all the time? And why is ^D echoed?

Comment: Thank you very much for doing all this research! It's very interesting to see the implementation.