# CTRL-D on Mac terminal outputs a D character

Tags: c, macos

I am running this example (from Kernighan and Ritchie's C book section 1.5.2) on a mac OS X machine terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if(c == '\n')
            ++nl;

    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

I run the app and enter the EOF character `CTRL-D` immediately. The program outputs `0D` and terminates. The 0 is the expected output, but where does the extra 'D' come from?

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364313/signal-eof-in-mac-osx-terminal) and [this faq](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/index.html), but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bet the terminal is showing a `^D` (normal caret notation) and leaving the cursor on the caret, then your program is printing `0\n` because `nl` is 0 overwriting the caret.

Adding a `sleep(5)` before the final `printf` should confirm this.

Comment: On the other hand I don't know whether it's *normal* for a terminal to print the `^D` there. I don't recall seeing it on other Unices.

Comment: Rather than sleeping, @Anand could just start their printf format with a \n, to make sure the output starts on a fresh line.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I found the answer in another post and for any new comers googling the answer. type in the mac terminal `stty -echoctl`

Credit goes to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)

full post and explanation on [Why does C...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306225/why-does-c-program-print-0d-instead-of-0-when-eof-sent-as-ctrld)