# programming c++ , get extra character 'D' after the result in my mac, but runs well in other unix server

Tags: c++, macos

This is  the code just trying to output the first number of a sequence.

but when i input`1 1`,finish with crtl+d the output is `1D` .When I input`-1 -1`finish with crtl+d the output is`-1`without a wierd 'D'.

Why will that D shows up. I think the code is right and it maybe some update in terminal or g++ that cause the problem. Is anyone has some other ideas?

P.S. I use g++ to compile and it works good on teacher's unix platform.
The code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
std::vector <int> N;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   int tok;
   while (std::cin >> tok){N.push_back(tok);}
   std::cout << N[0]<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're seeing the "D" from hitting "^D" (and then overwriting the "^". `echo "1 1" | ./a.out` doesn't produce that output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CTRL-D on Mac terminal outputs a D character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756825/ctrl-d-on-mac-terminal-outputs-a-d-character)

Comment: @Wooble, thank you very much. it works. But can I just input and get the output without D? Because in Unix , i don't have that problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Yes, I have seen this question.The method provided is successful in C. But I am not an expert. I don't know how to do this in c++.

Comment: Well, `sleep()` isn't really a solution to the problem, IMO. Normal unix tools that read from stdin and write to stdout don't seem to do this on OS X, and they don't rely on sleeping.